# Vmplayer VM unroutable to VirtualBox VMs In The Same Subnet (and vice versa)

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-player

I'm running into an issue where I have Vmplayer and VirtualBox VMs both bridged, using dhcp, reaches the external network, and other hosts on the network can ping all the VMs. However, Vmplayer VMs and VirtualBox VMs can't ping each other.

These are the test results:

```
Vmplayer VMs _can_ ping other Vmplayer VMs

VirtualBox VMs _can_ ping other VirtualBox VMs

Other hosts can ping _both_ Vmplayer VMs and VirtualBox VMs

Vmplayer VMs _can't_ ping VirtualBox VMs

VirtualBox VMs _can't_ ping Vmplayer VMs
```

Vmplayer VM Routing Table:

```
[root@smartos ~]# netstat -rn

Routing Table: IPv4
  Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface 
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- --------- 
default              10.0.1.1             UG        4       1022 e1000g0   
10.0.1.0             10.0.1.7             U         4       1272 e1000g0   
127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            UH        2         14 lo0
```

VirtualBox VM Routing Table:

```
$ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use  Netif Expire
default            10.0.1.1           UGS         0     2883    em0
10.0.1.0/24        link#1             U           0     1036    em0
10.0.1.22          link#1             UHS         0        0    lo0
127.0.0.1          link#2             UH          0        0    lo0
```

[image: Vmplayer Network Settings]
[image: VirtualBox Network Settings]

Comment: You'll need to provide example IPs and static route examples.  However, my gut tells me the issue is the VMs don't know how to route to each other, because the static routes aren't complete.  You can confirm this with traceroute.

Comment: @CIA I'll add the routing tables of the VMs. But other hosts on the network are able to reach them, and they are able to reach the hosts as well (and vice versa). That should mean the are routable to the gateway.

Comment: Do you have sample routes for one machine in the VB and one from the VM environments? Are the IPs assigned at random or is there a schema for VB vs VM machines?  Do you have the config/definitions for the `Link#1` and `Link#2` gateways in your VB host's routes or are they relative to their adapter number?

Comment: @CIA the server has a 4-port NIC adapter. Only Adapter #2 is linked. Adapter #2 is bridged to by both Vmplayer and VirtualBox. And both Vmplayer and VirtualBox have statically assigned IPs, subnets, and gateways.